# Passing parameters to sub reports in ssrs 2012

Tags: reporting-services, subreport, ssrs-2012

What is the different between Parameters!Country.Value and Fields(Parameters!Country.Value).value while passing Parameters to sub-Report in ssrs 2012

Comment: Fields(Parameter!Country.Value).Value didn't pass the parameter to sub-report

Comment: Where we can use this value "Fields(Parameter!Country.Value).Value " then?

Comment: Why do you think you need to?

Comment: I have one subreport. I want to send multiple values to the sub-Report without creating actual Parameter. 
For example, in my dataset I have one field "country". In the subreport I want to send the values of Country filed to subreport.

Comment: So in that case, are you looking for this?:  Fields!Country.Value